# How does OpenCV find chessboard corners?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

What are the internal workings of the OpenCV function [findChessboardCorners](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The source code of OpenCV is available, so I'd recommend just taking some time going through the code. The relevant file for this particular function is:

[calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp)

I've not looked into it in detail, but it looks like

```
CV_IMPL
int cvFindChessboardCorners( const void* arr, CvSize pattern_size,
                             CvPoint2D32f* out_corners, int* out_corner_count,
                             int flags )
```

is the main implementation of this method. In here they

1. Use `cvCheckChessboard` to determine if a chessboard is in the image
2. Convert to binary (B&W) and dilate to split the corners apart
3. Use `icvGenerateQuads` to find the squares.

The code then seems to go though a set of checks to condense these `quads` to chessboard corners, including `icvFindConnectedQuads`, `icvCleanFoundConnectedQuads` to remove extra corners, `icvCheckQuadGroup`, and `icvCheckBoardMonotony`.

All of these functions are implemented in the same file, apart from `cvCheckChessboard` which is in [calib3d/src/checkchessboard.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/checkchessboard.cpp). Depending how well you wanted to understand the code, there seem to be a number of debugging lines, which can be included if you `#define DEBUG_CHESSBOARD`, that may help you see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I could look it up, but I was just curious, but not curious enough to go through the source code. I hoped someone figured this out some time, and could explain the principles :)

Comment: I Found a nicely written paper...that also offers an alternative method that is more stable and faster (according to the author) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282446068_Automatic_chessboard_corner_detection_method